# Do client services need ports?

Tags: networking

Recently, I was having a chat with a much experienced engineer. We had a service on the server that only initiated requests to a partner. I suggested that this service requires us to configure a port and he turned down my suggestion. I believe he said something on the line of "Since we are not hosting a service that is not accessed by anyone rather we are accessing a partner's service, we don't require a port." It got me thinking, given on the same server, we have so many services, how does the server know that this response is for this given service?

Answer (score 0):

broadly, the server is really acting as a client and the ports used for connections are assigned dynamically by the networking stack

under normal conditions, the port

- is numbered >1000 (low ports are reserved for root processes)
- not in use